# Mock a function passed as default parameter

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I have a python file (`a.py`) which defines a function, and a class which uses it as a default parameter in it's init method and initializes another imported class. This is my `a.py`

```py
import OtherClass

def useful_default_func():
    //do something useful

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, def_func=useful_default_func):
        self.other_class = OtherClass(def_func())
        //do something useful
```

I am trying to mock the `useful_default_func` in my test file.

```py
class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('a.useful_default_func')
    @patch('a.OtherClass')
    test_init(self, mock_other_class, mock_default_func):
        myc= MyClass()
        mock_other_class.assert_called_once_with(mock_default_func)
        // further tests
```

However, the `mock_default_func` is not patching and my test fails saying,

```sh
Expected: OtherClass(<MagicMock id='xxx'>)
Actual: OtherClass(<function useful_default_func at 0x7f155858b378>)
```

Fairly new to the python mock lib, so not really sure, what is happening here or what I am doing wrong or how should I be approaching it?

Comment: The default parameter is bound when the class is created, *before* you patch. Why not explicitly pass in a mock, given it's parameterised? `myc = MyClass(def_func=mock_default_func)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I wanted to make sure that no one accidentally changes the default function. Like the default function to the class should always be `useful_default_func` in this case. Maybe there is another way to ensure that or I am not approaching it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work:

```
def mocked_fct():
    return 42

class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch.object(a.MyClass.__init__, '__defaults__', (mocked_fct,))
    @patch('a.OtherClass')
    def test_init(self, mock_other_class):
        myc = MyClass()
        mock_other_class.assert_called_once_with(mocked_fct)
```

I didn't use a mock for the mocked default function here, this can be changed if needed. The main point is that you can mock the function defaults.

**Note:** this assumes that you call

```
self.other_class = OtherClass(def_func)
```

instead of

```
self.other_class = OtherClass(def_func())
```

If this was not a typo, your assertion would not be correct. In this case, you could instead use:

```
mock_other_class.assert_called_once_with(mocked_fct())
mock_other_class.assert_called_once_with(42)  # same as above
```